# I cant figure out how to reference my table when filtering the results on my subform

Tags: ms-access, vba

The main table that I need to reference is AddInventory and the name of the subform is AddInventorySubform.

The code on subform load is:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Me.AddInventorysubform.Form.Filter = "[Submitted]= True"
Me.AddInventorysubform.Form.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

The code asks me to submit a value for submitted.

How would I reference the main form in the code?

Comment: The form containing a subform control is the Parent -- Me.Parent.

Answer (score 0):

Either you would have to put your code in the main Form_Load() or change it to reference the subform itself (since you put it in the subform's Form_Load()):

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.Filter = "[Submitted]= True"
    Me.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```